# GCP VM add to Existing On prem Window Server AD

Tags: windows, active-directory, google-cloud-platform

Suppose I have a on prem server with AD and server as AD Domain controller already. I am going to create a VM (window server 2016) on GCP.

Are there any method for me to add the new server into existing AD. I want to share the AD user to my window server on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Cloud Directory Sync](https://support.google.com/a/answer/106368?hl=en). Make sure you meet [the requirements](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6123896) beforehand. Afterwards, you can follow [this guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6120989) to get started.

Google has a very detailed [3-part article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-active-directory-introduction) explaining how everything works behind the scenes and all the different settings you can configure.